# Can I travel to Schengen countries, the US, or Canada with a convention travel document issued by Denmark?

Tags: visas, schengen, refugees

I am a refugee staying in Danmark, and I have a convention passport travel document. Can I travel to Schengen countries, USA or Canada?

Answer (score 2):

To travel to other Schengen countries, you don't need a convention travel document, just your residence permit card.

To travel to the US or Canada, you will need to apply for a US or Canadian visa using your convention travel document.  If the visa is granted, this will be indicated by a sticker affixed to one of the pages of your convention travel document.  With that, you will be able to travel to the country granting the visa.